# dependency not satisfiable fuse-utils

Tags: software-center, dependencies, deb, online-storage

I have looked around and the answers for dependency problems seem to be specific but I am sorry if this has already been answered. I am trying to install storage made easy desktop client but when I double click the .deb file I get

```
dependency not satisfiable fuse-utils
```

The output from gdebi package manager is:

```
E: storagemadeeasy: debian-changelog-file-missing E: storagemadeeasy:
no-copyright-file W: storagemadeeasy: description-too-long W:
storagemadeeasy: extended-description-line-too-long E:
storagemadeeasy: depends-on-obsolete-package depends: fuse-utils W:
storagemadeeasy: non-standard-executable-perm
usr/share/sme_install/XML-Simple-2.18.zip 0777 != 0755 W:
storagemadeeasy: non-standard-dir-perm
usr/share/sme_install/smeclient/ 0777 != 0755 W: storagemadeeasy:
non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/sme_install/smeexplorer/ 0777 != 0755
W: storagemadeeasy: non-standard-dir-perm
usr/share/sme_install/smesynccenter/ 0777 != 0755 W: storagemadeeasy:
non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/smeclient/exp/files/big/ 0777 != 0755
W: storagemadeeasy: non-standard-dir-perm
usr/share/smeclient/exp/files/small/ 0777 != 0755 W: storagemadeeasy:
binary-without-manpage usr/bin/smemount E: storagemadeeasy:
executable-desktop-file usr/share/applications/sme-client-kde.desktop
0755 E: storagemadeeasy: executable-desktop-file
usr/share/applications/sme-client.desktop 0755 E: storagemadeeasy:
executable-desktop-file
usr/share/applications/smeexplorer2-kde.desktop 0755 E:
storagemadeeasy: executable-desktop-file
usr/share/applications/smeexplorer2.desktop 0755 E: storagemadeeasy:
executable-desktop-file
usr/share/applications/smesynccenter2-kde.desktop 0755 E:
storagemadeeasy: executable-desktop-file
usr/share/applications/smesynccenter2.desktop 0755 W: storagemadeeasy:
desktop-command-not-in-package
usr/share/applications/sme-client-kde.desktop smeclient W:
storagemadeeasy: desktop-command-not-in-package
usr/share/applications/sme-client.desktop smeclient W:
storagemadeeasy: desktop-command-not-in-package
usr/share/applications/smeexplorer2-kde.desktop smeexplorer W:
storagemadeeasy: desktop-command-not-in-package
usr/share/applications/smeexplorer2.desktop smeexplorer W:
storagemadeeasy: desktop-command-not-in-package
usr/share/applications/smesynccenter2-kde.desktop smesynccenter W:
storagemadeeasy: desktop-command-not-in-package
usr/share/applications/smesynccenter2.desktop smesynccenter W:
storagemadeeasy: executable-not-elf-or-script
usr/share/sme_install/XML-Simple-2.18.zip W: storagemadeeasy:
executable-not-elf-or-script
usr/share/applications/smeexplorer2.desktop W: storagemadeeasy:
executable-not-elf-or-script
usr/share/applications/smesynccenter2.desktop W: storagemadeeasy:
executable-not-elf-or-script
usr/share/applications/smesynccenter2-kde.desktop W: storagemadeeasy:
executable-not-elf-or-script
usr/share/applications/smeexplorer2-kde.desktop W: storagemadeeasy:
executable-not-elf-or-script
usr/share/applications/sme-client-kde.desktop W: storagemadeeasy:
executable-not-elf-or-script usr/share/smeclient/exp/files/folder.gif
W: storagemadeeasy: executable-not-elf-or-script
usr/share/applications/sme-client.desktop W: storagemadeeasy:
possibly-insecure-handling-of-tmp-files-in-maintainer-script prerm:25

Lintian finished with exit status 1
```

Any ideas much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the same case or not but

make sure you are downloading the latest version from the site

http://storagemadeeasy.com/LinuxDrive/

there was an updated version to solve this issue with 13.10 .

Comment: ok just installed 14.04 so maybe thats the problem thanks

Comment: i just installed it this way on 14.04

Comment: Yeah you have to use version marked as for 13.10